# I can't remove the item from the list by the type of the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I don't know what to do, I want to remove the items from the list that are strings,
but seems it does not work. Pls help me

```
lista1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
lista2 = [1,2,3,4]
lista1.extend(lista2)


for i in lista1:
    if type(i) == str:
        lista1.remove(i)
```

print(lista1)

Comment: use `isinstnace(i, str)` to check a type

Comment: by the way the elements of `lista1` are all strings so the conditional is not needed because is always true

Comment: @cards `lista1` is extended by `lista2`, so not all the items are string.

Comment: My bad! Yes...so the problem is just there, the `extend`! do `b = lista1.copy()
lista1.extend(lista2)
for i in b: lista1.remove(i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
lista1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
lista2 = [1,2,3,4]
lista1.extend(lista2)

non_string_list = list(filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str), lista1))
print(non_string_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't remove the items in the for loop.  When you remove 'a' , the next index it checks is lista1[1].  Since 'a' is removed, lista1[1] is now 'c' instead of 'b'.  It will skip 'b' because of this.  One solution could be to make a copy of lista1 and remove items from that as it loops through the original.